# Output Taxonomy Terms in Main Query WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm very much a PHP noob so please bear with me. I'm using Beaver Builder in WordPress and using a posts module with the main query setting.

I have a custom taxonomy for locations and I want to return all the locations in the query.

This is what I have so far;

```
function hen_locations_query( $query ) {
if ( $query->is_page( $page = 'hen-locations' ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $terms = get_terms( 'hen-locations' );
   }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'hen_locations_query' );
```

Any suggestions/ideas, please let me konw.

Comment: This one taxonomy or simple category of posts ?

Comment: One custom taxonomy. Not the default posts category.

Answer (score 0):

[More information](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

```
function cat_based_filter( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_page( $page = 'hen-locations' ) && $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {

         $query->set( 'tax_query', array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'hen-locations', // change here your taxonomy
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'add-cat-slug', // add category slug here
                'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        ) );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'cat_based_filter' );
```

Comment: My tax is called 'hen-locations'. Didn't seem to work for me.